# Pandas: how to add a column with a value based on conditions on differents columns

Tags: pandas, numpy, group-by, dataset

I'm analyzing a dataset of internet communictions that consists of 5 columns and below an example of it

| IPSrc | IPDst | PortSrc | PortDst | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IP1 | IP2 | Pr1 | Pr2 | 35 |
| IP3 | IP4 | Pr3 | Pr4 | 36 |
| IP2 | IP1 | Pr2 | Pr1 | 88 |
| IP4 | IP3 | Pr4 | Pr3 | 150 |
| IP5 | IP6 | Pr5 | Pr6 | 11 |
| IP1 | IP4 | Pr8 | Pr9 | 36 |

I would like to get the same dataset but with a new columns **Length 2**, where Length 2 is the value of the row that match those conditions:

```
IPSrc = IPDst
IPDst = IPSrc
PortSrc = PortDst
PortDst = PortSrc
```

So in this example, the ideal results would be:

| IPSrc | IPDst | PortSrc | PortDst | Length | Length 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IP1 | IP2 | Pr1 | Pr2 | 35 | 88 |
| IP3 | IP4 | Pr3 | Pr4 | 36 | 150 |
| IP2 | IP1 | Pr2 | Pr1 | 88 | 35 |
| IP4 | IP3 | Pr4 | Pr3 | 150 | 36 |
| IP5 | IP6 | Pr5 | Pr6 | 11 |  |
| IP1 | IP4 | Pr8 | Pr9 | 36 |  |

Knowing that the dataset contains 1 million rows, it would be appreciated if the given answers would considerate the performance.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with matching column converted to `index` with columns in parameter `on`:

```
df = df.join(df.set_index(['IPSrc','PortSrc'])['Length'].rename('Length 2'), 
             on=['IPDst','PortDst'])
print (df)
  IPSrc IPDst PortSrc PortDst  Length  Length 2
0   IP1   IP2     Pr1     Pr2      35      88.0
1   IP3   IP4     Pr3     Pr4      36     150.0
2   IP2   IP1     Pr2     Pr1      88      35.0
3   IP4   IP3     Pr4     Pr3     150      36.0
4   IP5   IP6     Pr5     Pr6      11       NaN
5   IP1   IP4     Pr8     Pr9      36       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there a possibility to get more detail about this solution? I mean what is the logic behind?

Comment: @KhalilYoucefLagraa - It is used left join by `DataFrame.join` with match between `IPSrc = IPDst
IPDst = IPSrc
PortSrc = PortDst
PortDst = PortSrc` by converting `['IPSrc','PortSrc']` to `MultiIndex` and then is matching with columns `['IPDst','PortDst']`

Comment: Executed on my dataset and it generate this error: **ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Length 2'], dtype='object')**

Any Idea?

Comment: @KhalilYoucefLagraa - then `.rename('Length 2')` change to `.rename('Length 3')`

Comment: @KhalilYoucefLagraa - error means in original dataframe already exist `Length 2` column, so rename to `Length 3` should working well

Comment: Even tho I'm getting an empty results, I appreciate your time @jezrael

Comment: @KhalilYoucefLagraa then it is dáta related problem, with sample working well